# Req: to reopen Young professional co-worker thinks she is not performing enough (DONE)

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

[Young professional co-worker thinks she is not performing enough](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/123065/young-professional-co-worker-thinks-she-is-not-performing-enough)

Close reason:

> This question appears to be off-topic. The users who voted to close gave this specific reason:
>
> - "Questions require a goal that we can address. Rather than explaining the difficulties of your situation, explain what you want to do to make it better. For more information, see this meta post." – gnat, Rui F Ribeiro, Lightness Races in Orbit, T. Sar, Michael Grubey

Mentoring is absolutely a topic we can address

Comment: how did this get closed? Once it was open for near 24H I thought it was in the clear!

Comment: @SaggingRufus The usual suspects, who we are not allowed to name, did it.

That's nothing, I had once put out a bounty that was reversed and I was accused of blocking close votes for my trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That didn't take long - the question is already reopened.